# Can I get more results/options from /users/{ids}/top-answer-tags?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api-v2

/users/{ids}/top-answer-tags returns the top 30 tags for a given user.  It's also the only endpoint that returns the user's tag scores along with the rest of the tag info.  I'd like to use this data if possible.

The limited options are kind of crippling me though.  I'd like some additional flexibility - would it be possible for this endpoint to accept "page" parameters, and (bonus points!) allow me to set min/max score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No can do on the min/max score, but more results are now available on that method (as well as /top-question-tags).

[Example](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answer-tags-on-users#id=80572&filter=!-psgKvkQ&site=stackoverflow&run=true)