# Documentation of /users/{id}/top-answer-tags conflicts with implementation.

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, documentation

According to the documentation:

> [/users/{id}/top-answer-tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/top-answer-tags-on-users) or [/me/top-answer-tags](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-top-answer-tags) – Get the top 30 tags (by score) a single user has posted answers in.

However in practice, when retrieving data from [this URL](http://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/users/235/top-answer-tags?filter=%21DnBO_&site=askubuntu&page=1), I get a response with `total` set to 378 - this is correctly flagged as an error by my test suite since it conflicts with the definition provided above.

I assume that either this route returns *more* than the top 30 tags (and the documentation is incorrect) or the route does *not* return more than 30 tags (and the implementation is incorrect). Judging from the fact that I can retrieve page 2 from the results, I assume the former.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kevin was nice enough to grant my [recent feature request](https://stackapps.com/questions/2976/can-i-get-more-results-options-from-users-ids-top-answer-tags) on this endpoint, so it now returns "paged" results instead of a static top 30.  I'm guessing the documentation just wasn't updated to reflect the change.

I've tested it (StinkingBadges is using this functionality) and can confirm that your test result is the current "correct" behavior.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Then the only problem now is the documentation.